# How to concatenate? String + the math thank you

Tags: javascript, concatenation

Hey guys I am new to javascript and I was really hoping someone can explain to me how to concatenate this particular example: The sum of 3 and 5 and 1 is 9. The square root of 9 is 3.00.  Just some background info on the code that I have done so far and what the goal here is. This is a supposed to be a calculator that has an alert box pop up and this calculator has three text fields and the text that is supposed to come up should look like the above example except with the numbers the user inputs into the field. 
the code I currently have and which does not work is this.

```js
function add() {

  //parseInt is basically converting from string to integer 
  var myNumber1 = parseInt(document.getElementById('Number1').value);
  var myNumber2 = parseInt(document.getElementById('Number2').value);
  var myNumber3 = parseInt(document.getElementById('Number3').value);

  var mysum = myNumber1 + myNumber2 + myNumber3;
  var mysqrt = Math.sqrt(mysum);
  
  alert("The sum of") myNumber1 + "and"
  myNumber2 + "and"
  myNumber3 + "is"
  mysum);
  
}
```

```html
<h2>Web Calculator</h2>
<form>
  Number1:<input type="text" id="Number1" /><br /> Number2:
  <input type="text" id="Number2" /><br /> Number3:
  <input type="text" id="Number3" /><br />
  <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="add()">

</form>
```

Comment: The code you posted has syntax errors. Are those really in your code? If not, can you fix the post?

Comment: you need this https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/talks/wat also, check your extra bracket: alert("The sum of" + myNumber1 ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you posted is fine but just has syntax errors. You need to use the `+` operator to concatenate strings and variables inside an `alert()`.

So something like `alert(var1 + "string1" + var2)`

Here's a working snippet. Is this what you want?

```js
function add() {
  //parseInt is basically converting from string to integer 
  var myNumber1 = parseInt(document.getElementById('Number1').value);
  var myNumber2 = parseInt(document.getElementById('Number2').value);
  var myNumber3 = parseInt(document.getElementById('Number3').value);
  var mysum = myNumber1 + myNumber2 + myNumber3;
  var mysqrt = Math.sqrt(mysum);
  alert("The sum of " + myNumber1 + " and " +
    myNumber2 + " and " +
    myNumber3 + " is " +
    mysum);
  alert("The square root of " + mysum + " is " + mysqrt);
}
```

```html
<head>
  <title>Lab6</title>
  <h2>Web Calculator</h2>
  <form>
    Number1:<input type="text" id="Number1" /><br /> Number2:
    <input type="text" id="Number2" /><br /> Number3:
    <input type="text" id="Number3" /><br />
    <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="add()">

  </form>
```

Comment: Wow yeah, that's what I was looking for thanks. Just to be clear my mistake was the syntax error correct? So, in this case, was it the lack of spaces I had? And the plus sign that I missed in the beginning.

Comment: It was the `+` signs in your alert. You forgot them between the strings at the end of the lines and the variable on the next line. Check [this link](http://2ality.com/2011/10/string-concatenation.html) for more info about concatenation in javascript. Also make sure you mark the answer as accepted if it works for you!